# PC asks for a password I didn't set

Tags: windows

I removed my old password on my laptop, and when I opened it it asked for a password. I dont have a Windows 10 account so I dont have any means of opening it. Can anyone help?

Im using Asus K555L

Comment: Is the old password working?

Comment: no. any of my past passwords arent working :(

Comment: @divin3 I cant access with any of my past passwords

Comment: In the bottom left of the screen there should appear your local username. Try selecting it and try again. see on picture: http://www.tenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/26170d1438029241-sign-screen-background-image-enable-disable-windows-10-a-default_sign_in_screen.jpg where `Brink2` is, there should be your local username as well.

Comment: @divin3 for some reason that button is gone as well there is literally no way of getting in

Comment: You last comment does not make a great deal of sense.  If you cannot log into a user account how do you have a start button?

Comment: I know it sounds silly but have you tried to sign in with providing a password? I have gotten stuck on login on service laptop and not tries blank password.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to another PC then try this;

- Download Hirens Boot CD ISO file from http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/
- Burn it onto a CD using imgburn.
- Boot your PC with the CD.
- Follow the instructions here http://www.hirensbootcd.org/resetting-windows-password/

I am not sure if this will work on a Windows 10 PC.

Comment: Please add the essential steps from the external page. If the link becomes invalid, this answer might not be very helpful anymore.